# If separation of structure, style and functionality is the key to the modern web, why use jquery to manipulate the style of anything?

Tags: jquery, css, dom, separation-of-concerns

**Background for the question:**
I have been studying web topics in a abstract way for awhile. This means I read alot about trending technologies, I get the hang of using them at a very basic level, then I move on. The reason I have to learn this way is that in order to have the motivation to master something I must first see for myself the importance of the technology in the big picture.

**Main Questions:**

If I am supposed to keep HTML, CSS and Javascript separate, why would I want to manipulate the DOM and insert styling with a tool like jQuery?

Why not just structure and style it the way I would like the first time?

I understand certain principals such as hiding elements until an event triggers them. But why would I need to do any styling with jQuery?

Comment: I think this belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com.  See: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/about

Comment: Edge cases. If you need one div to be yellow with 12px verdana font specifically 200 x 200 px and a border it does not make sense to make a class specifically for that.